# presto-server directory structure after pulling 0.221

Tags: maven, presto

I just pulled latest presto code (version 0.221).

My previous version was 0.218.

The problem is that 'maven install' is creating following target directory structure after pull:

```
presto-server/target/presto-server-0.221-SNAPSHOT/presto-server-0.221-SNAPSHOT/lib
```

Before the pull, it was this:

```
presto-server/target/presto-server-0.221-SNAPSHOT/lib
```

This is breaking all my devops scrips. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you update to Presto version `311`? https://prestosql.io/download.html

If you run into any problems with it, there are many people on the community Slack who can help you quickly: https://prestosql.io/community.html